# Get number of objects inside a collection of arrays JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have a collection of arrays each with a dynamic number of objects inside them:

```
arr1=[obj1, obj2, obj3, other1, other2]
arr2=[obj1, obj2, other1]
...//some more arrays with any number of objects inside them
```

I want to count the number of objects in total, ignoring the "others" and only counting "obj" objects.

I'm not sure if i can achieve this with array destructuring, or not.
Any ideas?

Comment: From what it is, I believe you should not take user input to directly give into RegEx variable.

Comment: So how should i do it?

Comment: Find all the possible reserved / mess-uppable characters for RegEx that user can enter and replace them with safe ones or escape them.

Comment: The bracket '(' is a regular expression character for group, meaning that you're not escaping it.

Comment: i'm aware of this, but how can i make my regex ignore that from user input?

Comment: try setting the keyword like this: (e) => setKeyword(e.target.value.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')) 
does that works?

Comment: thanks for your help, yes Praveen's answer already helped me!

Answer (score 1):

There's no avoiding iterating over the array for this, but you can do it implicitly.

Assuming you have a function called `objDetector` that returns `true` if an element should be counted and `false` otherwise, you can do:

```
const numberOfObjs = arr.filter(objDetector).length
```

Comment: and objDetector is a function?

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of objects inside an array by looping through each value
and check if that value is an object.

```
var objects_count = 0;

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(arr[i]) == 'object') {
        objects_count += 1;
    }
}
```

in this case, `objects_count` will be the number of objects in the array.